# Converting Ed25519 public key to a Curve25519 public key

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519

I [understand that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve#Equivalence_with_twisted_Edwards_curves):

$$x_{montgomery} = \frac{1 + y_{edwards}}{1 - y_{edwards}}$$

Using the [libsodium ed25519 implementation](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/tree/master/src/libsodium/crypto_sign/ed25519/ref10), I have tried to write the following:

```
void keypair_2(unsigned char *pk, unsigned char *sk)
{
    ge_p3 A;
    int i;

    sk[0] &= 248;
    sk[31] &= 63;
    sk[31] |= 64;

    ge_scalarmult_base(&A,sk); // generate ed25519 public from sk.

    fe one;
    fe u, v, vinv;
    fe montx;
    fe_1(one);
    fe_sub(v, one, A.Y); //v = 1-y
    fe_add(u, A.Y, one); //u = y+1
    fe_invert(vinv, v); //vinv = v^(-1) = (1-y)^(-1)
    fe_mul(montx, u, vinv); //montx = u/v = (y+1)/(1-y)
    fe_tobytes(pk, montx);
}
```

And I have compared this against the curve25519 implementation, but I am getting differing results.

I am unsure as to my error.

Comment: In my own application I chose to use Ed25519 public keys in the public API, even for key-exchange. Then convert the public key to montgomery during key-exchange. That's slightly more expensive, but makes the API nicer since there is only one kind of public key visible to the consumer. I also think that it's possible to convert the key-exchange to use Ed25519 natively, removing the performance penalty, but didn't get around to investigating that yet.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I am doing the same (using Ed25519 as the public key). It is probably possible to implement DH in Ed25519 natively, but I am not sufficiently confident in my ability to do so without messing up. I understand ImperialViolet has such an implementation?

Comment: You can add https://github.com/nightcracker/ed25519/blob/master/src/key_exchange.c to your project. It should be compatible with the rest of your implementation. It takes an Ed25519 public key, converts it to montgomery, and then computes a scalar multiplication. Don't forget to add a hashing step in the end, preferably one that's compatible with NaCl. That's what I do in my C# port.

Comment: Support for this has now (2014-08-05) been added to Sodium. [Implement ed25519 -> curve25519 keys conversion](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/commit/eae4add8de435a7fad08eab4f6e7cbfa9209a692#diff-9f8d35b5046ff922edb045b081249af6R38) Look at [`test/default/ed25519_convert.c`](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/master/test/default/ed25519_convert.c) for some example code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ge_scalarmult_base` returns `GroupElementP3` which doesn't have `(x, y)` as members. It has `X, Y, Z` from which you can compute `x = X / Z` and `y = Y / Z`.

So you have two choices:

1. Compress the point with `ge_tobytes`:

   ```
   byte[32] Abytes;
   fe y;

   ge_scalarmult_base(&A,sk);

   ge_tobytes(Abytes, &A);
   fe_frombytes(&y, Abytes);

   // your code here using `y` instead of `A.Y`
   ```

   The downside of this technique is that it costs two field inversions. So I'd only use it if the input is a compressed point.
2. Modify the formula to work with X, Y, Z coordinates:

   $$x_{mont} = \frac{1+y_{ed}}{1-y_{ed}} = \frac{1+\frac{Y}{Z}}{1-\frac{Y}{Z}} = \frac{Z+Y}{Z-Y}$$

   ```
   fe_sub(v, A.Z, A.Y); //v = Z - Y
   fe_add(u, A.Y, A.Z); //u = Z + Y
   ```

   This solution is preferable if you just computed the point without having reduced yet. Typically directly after a scalar multiplication.