# Curve25519 over Ed25519 for key exchange? Why?

Tags: elliptic-curves, key-exchange, dsa, ed25519

I've been reading up on the Signal Protocol (in this [PDF](https://dspace.cvut.cz/bitstream/handle/10467/76230/F8-DP-2018-Rubin-Jan-thesis.pdf?sequence=-1)) and it seems to be using [Curve25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519) for ECDH and [EdDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA) (with Ed25519) for signatures.

My question is why not use only Ed25519?

[This implementation](https://github.com/orlp/ed25519) supports Ed25519 and key exchange so what is Curve25519 needed for?

Are there any security considerations where it beats Ed25519 key exchange?

[This question from CryptoSE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27866/why-curve25519-for-encryption-but-ed25519-for-signatures) answered why to use Ed25519 over Curve25519 for signatures but why not to use Ed25519 for key exchange?

Comment: I would argue that [my answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/43058/15312) you cited says that curve25519 allows for a faster variable base scalar multiplication than ed25519. And key exchange requires a variable base scalar multiplication. Even the library you cited, internally, performs the key exchange on curve25519.

Comment: Hey Ruggero, thanks for your answer. You said in your answer "the fixed-base algorithm of Ed25519 is, on most platform, faster than the variable-base of X25519." (line 24 of your answer), also how do you know the library internally performs the key exchange on Curve25519? (as far as I know Curve25519 uses 32 bytes private keys and the library uses 64 bytes private keys)

Comment: @OughToPrevail there [is](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13077/can-curve25519-keys-be-used-with-ed25519-keys) [a](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9536/converting-ed25519-public-key-to-a-curve25519-public-key) [relationship](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26966/how-to-derive-the-curve-ed25519-from-curve25519) between the curves and if you look at [the source](https://github.com/orlp/ed25519/blob/master/src/key_exchange.c) you may see the conversion from edwards to montgomery.

Comment: Oh, so as long as I stick to the library I will be using Curve25519 with Ed25519?

Comment: btw @Ruggero I am not so good in math so I don't really understand https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26966/how-to-derive-the-curve-ed25519-from-curve25519 but thank you

Comment: Yes, I asked @Ruggero "so as long as I stick to the library I will be using Curve25519 with Ed25519?". Still waiting for an answer

Comment: Thank you @SqueamishOssifrage for the very elaborated and helpful answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's a few different related parts here, and the nomenclature of the library you've cited is a little confusing.

- **Curve25519** is an elliptic curve over the finite field $\mathbb F_p$, where $p = 2^{255} - 19$, whence came the 25519 part of the name.  Specifically, it is the *Montgomery* curve $y^2 = x^3 + 486662 x^2 + x$, but you don't need to know the details other than that it was designed to admit fast computation of $x([n]P)$ given $n$ and $x(P)$ which is useful for Diffie–Hellman key agreement.

  <sup>(Side note: Sometimes the Montgomery form is written with the letters $u$ and $v$ as in $v^2 = u^3 + 486662 u^2 + u$, especially when drawing a contrast to another form like Weierstrass or Edwards.)</sup>
- **X25519** is a Diffie–Hellman function built out of Curve25519.  An X25519 public key is the encoding of the $x$ coordinate of a point on Curve25519, hence the name X25519.

  <sup>(Historical note: Originally, X25519 was called Curve25519, but now Curve25519 just means the elliptic curve and X25519 means the cryptosystem.)</sup>
- **Edwards25519** is an elliptic curve over the same field, with a different shape, the twisted Edwards shape $-x^2 + y^2 = 1 - (121665/121666) x^2 y^2$, which admits fast computation of $P + Q$ given the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $P$ and $Q$.  It is related to Curve25519 by a birational map, so most points on Curve25519 can be mapped to edwards25519 and vice versa.
- **Ed25519** is a public-key signature scheme built out of edwards25519, using the EdDSA construction.  An Ed25519 public key is the encoding of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a point on edwards25519.

Curve25519 and X25519 were developed first; then Harold Edwards came along and blew the minds of Dan Bernstein and Tanja Lange by inventing Edwards curves which let you compute $P + Q$ *in constant time* faster than any other curve shapes and competitively with variable-time (*i.e.*, leaky) formulas for other curve shapes.  Fortuitously, it turned out that Curve25519 was birationally equivalent to a (twisted) Edwards curve, leading to Ed25519.  **Under the birational equivalence of Curve25519 and edwards25519, each X25519 public key corresponds to two possible Ed25519 public keys.**  As Ruggero explained, Curve25519 admits faster variable-base scalar multiplication, while edwards25519 admits faster fixed-base scalar multiplication and double-base scalar multiplication.

So what do you do if you want to use the same key material for key agreement and signature?  There are a few options:

- **The library you cited uses edwards25519 points as public keys, and converts them on the fly to Curve25519 $x$ coordinates for key agreement.  This is simple and works if you have full control over the public key format and can choose to use edwards25519 points.**  It's confusing to call the function `ed25519_key_exchange`, but such is life.
- XEd25519 as used by Signal uses Curve25519 $x$ coordinates as public keys, and for signatures, *always chooses the ‘positive’ point* on edwards25519 as a corresponding Ed25519 public key.  This is useful if you already have a lot of public keys deployed and you really don't want to redeploy them just to determine which ones are positive and which ones are negative.
- The signature scheme qDSA, following an idea used in Mike Hamburg's Strobe, uses Curve25519 $x$ coordinates as public keys, and uses a variant of the EdDSA signature equation to take advantage of the Montgomery ladder and avoid the Edwards shape and point addition altogether.  This is useful if you want very small code like on a microcontroller, where there is a high cost to having several different scalar multiplication routines, *e.g.* for fixed-base *vs.* double-base.

Comment: Hello, I came back here to try to understand this again but I do have a few questions relating to this answer: What do you mean by always choosing a positive point, and also what do you mean redeploy them?

Comment: @OughtToPrevail Positive point: It is an arbitrary choice which subset of points you label positive and which subset of points you label negative, as long as $-x$ is negative whenever $x$ is positive (and nonzero).

Comment: @OughtToPrevail Redeploy them: If you have already published the telephone book with everyone's public key in it, and you don't want throw them all out and publish a new one to replace the old telephone book, then you can use XEd25519.  But if you haven't published a telephone book at all yet, you don't need XEd25519.

Comment: Ok... positive I mostly understand and I guess redeploy too, thank you. But when does the redeploy occur for Curves unlike XEd25519 and why does the redployment occur?

Comment: @OughtToPrevail If you have _already printed_ a telephone book for X25519 keys, it will be missing some information: namely, the choice of $y$ coordinate for each key, among the two options determined by the $x$ coordinate (because $x^3 + 486662 x^2 + x$ has two possible square roots, unless $x = 0$).  Had you used Ed25519 from the beginning, you would have published that information in the telephone book anyway.  So, if you can do that, go for it!  But if you already published a telephone book with only the $x$ coordinates, XEd25519 lets you do signatures anyway with a little more work.

Comment: Oh interesting, so just making sure I understand, Ed25519 keys contain the full information of the x and y coordinates and X25519 only contain the X coordinates which have 2 possible y values, a positive and a negative, which XEd25519 solves by always choosing the positive. But if that is true why would anyone go with XEd25519 if Ed25519 will be easier? Is there a change of performance? Also, thank you :P

Comment: @OughtToPrevail You can use XEd25519 if you have already published a telephone book with X25519 public keys (the $x$ coordinates) and you don't want to republish it with Ed25519 public keys ($x$ and $y$ coordinates).  This literally happened with Signal's book mapping telephone numbers to public keys!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92832/discussion-between-oughttoprevail-and-squeamish-ossifrage).

Comment: I have started a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92832/discussion-between-oughttoprevail-and-squeamish-ossifrage)

Comment: I'm trying to understand your comment: 'and converts them on the fly to Curve25519 x coordinates for key agreement. ' So is the library in question just doing X25519? What should be a better name of the function?

Comment: @DavyLandman No, that library is for Ed25519, but `ed25519_key_exchange()` creates a DH shared key, which is what X25519 does. It would make more sense to call that function `x25519_key_exchange()`.