# Does any $x < p$ satisfy the curve equation of X25519?

Tags: elliptic-curves, x25519

I've been reading about the famous X25519, a montgomery curve from [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519)  and in that article they say that we ***do not have to check*** for point validity. Is it because that any $x < p$ satisfy the curve equation ? Is this possible for  X25519 because it is a Montgomery curve or because it was specifically designed to do so (**for the sake of efficiency,  and more possibilities for public keys**) by its discoverer Dan Bernstein ? Why every $x < p $ does **not** satisfy the curve equation for other curves like SECP256k1, where the equations are of the Weierstrass form, $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b
    \mod p  $ ? I would really like to know the mathematical reasons behind it. Thankyou everyone in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an elliptic curve given by the equation $y^2 = f(x) \bmod p$, then for each $x$, either $f(x)$ is a square modulo $p$, and there exists a square root $y$ such that $(x,y)$ and $(x,-y)$ satisfy the curve equation. If $f(x)$ is not a square modulo $p$, then this value $x$ does not correspond to a point on the curve, but to a point on the quadratic twist of the curve.

Therefore knowing only $x$, we know it corresponds to a point on the curve or its quadratic twist. The thing is that many standardized curves have a weak quadratic twist (see this page on [SafeCurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/twist.html) so it is mandatory to check the point is on the curve, and if we use only the $x$-coordinate, we still need to check it is not on the quadratic twist to avoid invalid curve attacks.

Dan Bernstein designed X25519 as a Diffie-Hellman function using Curve25519 in its Montgomery form. On this curve, the Montgomery ladder scalar multiplication is efficient and uses only the $x$-coordinate of the points. Then, manipulated points lie on the curve or its quadratic twist which is as secure as the original curve. Then any $x$ is valid, but does not necessarily correspond to a point on the curve.

Comment: Thankyou, for your answer! Can you please show me from where I can learn how the standard equations for point addition / doubling are mathematically derived. Programmatically implementing them was easy but I would really like to know the math behind it in simple ways and why all those same equations are valid modulo **p**

Comment: You mean: there exist $y$, whose square is $f(x)$.

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, only then the curve equation can be satisfied.

Comment: @VivekanandV A start would be to take a look at [Christof Paar's lectures](https://youtu.be/vnpZXJL6QCQ). I started with this years ago when I became interested in cryptography. You can also watch [DJB and Tanja Lange introduction to elliptic curves](https://youtu.be/vEt-D8xZmgE) explaining how it works starting from clocks to Edwards form of elliptic curves. Finally, the book [Elliptic Curves, Number Theory and Cryptography](https://people.cs.nctu.edu.tw/~rjchen/ECC2012S/Elliptic%20Curves%20Number%20Theory%20And%20Cryptography%202n.pdf) has more technical details (see chapter 2 for basics).

Comment: [Historical note: Originally, X25519 was called Curve25519, but now Curve25519 just means the elliptic curve and X25519 means the cryptosystem.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68129/18298)